# Equivalent in java API to LdapCtxFactory?

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I'm using LdapCtxFactory to query some searches in a LDAP AD, but eclipse shows me a warning

```
Access restriction: The type 'LdapCtxFactory' is not API (restriction on required library '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar')
```

But I can't find an equivalent in Java 8.

This is the code

```
@Override
    public String executeQuery(String query, String attribute) { //(

        Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<>();
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapUser);
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPassword);

        String value = "";

        try {
            DirContext context = LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance("ldap://" + adHost + '/', props);

            SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
            controls.setSearchScope(SUBTREE_SCOPE);

            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> renum = context.search(activeDirectoryName, query, controls);
            if (!renum.hasMore()) {
                logger.error("Error while querying from ldap");

            }
            SearchResult result = renum.next();

            value = result.getAttributes().get(attribute).get().toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Ha ocurrido un error al recuperar el atributo \"{}\" de AD", "", e);
        }

        return value;

    }
```

I want to get rid of the HastTable too, but "getLdapCtxInstance" only admits HastTables

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because your Eclipse build path is pointing to the JRE instead of the JDK.

Go to `Project -> Build Path ->Configure Build Path`, remove the JRE (and any other extraneous libraries or versions) in the Libraries tab, and add the JDK. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Any ideas where is the JDK in ubuntu? I've checked and I'm using JRE, but can't find JDK

Comment: It's usually in  /usr/lib/jvm/(jdkwithversionnumber)/, but could be different in your system. Also, are you sure you've installed JDK?

Comment: I've followed some tutorials like this,http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html  but they only install JRE but not JDK. Can't find how to install Oracle JDK specifically.

Comment: Managed to change to JDK, but still importing a SUN class com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory

Comment: This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824232/why-dont-i-have-this-class-when-it-is-supposed-to-be-in-rt-jar) could probably help you